# XSD(src. schema) + DAT(dest. schema) => XSLT (mapping) ===> XSLT + XML(src. data) => DAT(dest. data)

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

I have an XSD and I will provide a mapping UI for this XSD to display to the user to get the selected fields. And these selected fileds will be mapped against a DAT fields file in the same UI.

With these information i wanted to create a XSLT(mapping) dynamically (based on DAT field selection & XSD Filed selection), where DAT fields are hard coded from the selection but the XSD Field selection should have related XPATH from the user selection.

Based on this generated XSLT and an XML which conforms to the XSD used in the mapping UI, i want to generate the DAT file using the XSLT.

Will this approach works out?

I bet there are various better approaches available (other than using any third party products such as altova).

I am looking for a custom .NET solution & approach.

Comment: By "DAT" do you mean generic data or something more specific?

Comment: Kind of txt file with some field & record & record type delimiters

Comment: Your question as currently stated is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are tools like Altova's MapForce that attempt to do this kind of thing. My (limited) experience is that the technique only works if the XML is very simple.